# How to use ContentCachingResponseWrapper to read httpServletResponse?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I want to read the response body in my interceptor for logging.After I searched some answers, I tend to use `ContentCachingResponseWrapper`.here is my code:

```
public class CustomerInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter{
    public void poseHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        ContentCachingResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(response);
        byte[] contentAsByteArray = responseWrapper.getContentAsByteArray();
        ...
    }
```

But when I debug it .I got responseWrapper with content "".But In the postman I get the response body. Then I go to the source code.

```
private final FastByteArrayOutputStream content = new FastByteArrayOutputStream(1024);

public ContentCachingResponseWrapper(HttpServletResponse response) {
    super(response);
}
```

It seems that I didn't init the content.I know something is wrong in my code.My question is how to use `ContentCachingResponseWrapper` correctly?

Comment: Thank for your reply. I had read that answer. My question is in the interceptor , the `contentAsByteArray` is an empty String.

Comment: You need to wrap response with this wrapper using a filter, interceptor wont do. This is displayed in the question I linked. You can use interceptor to log result, but this seems unnecessary since you still need a filter for wrapping..

Comment: It seems that you are right. But why in interceptor it doesn't works,I'm confuse about that.

Comment: Because with filter you can pass your wrapper further using 'filterChain.doFilter', but with interceptor you cannot.

Comment: In that case , can I replace the `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` in a customer `DispatcherServlet`?

Comment: No, filter is the only option.